# AngularFire2 app.auth is not a function

Tags: angular, angularfire2

So I have been trying to experiment with Angular and Firebase, and wanted to get the angularfire2 auth system working. I followed some online tutorials and frankensteined this app together. I have a little experience in Angular2 doing a project ionic app a year or so ago but have not worked with Firebase though.

The error is when I `ng serve` get hit with a blank screen and a console **error**:

> TypeError app.auth is not a function

Seems this must be caused by an incorrect setup of the `AngularFireAuthModule` or something?

I referred to the https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md and it seems correct. Here is a link to the app https://github.com/jburns24/angularfire2-auth-bad-demo.

Seems like the exact issue mentioned in this [AngularFire2 TypeError: app.auth is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431735/angularfire2-typeerror-app-auth-is-not-a-function).

Comment: Looks as if this may be an issue with the angularfire2 and firebase package there is an open issue https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1707

Answer (score 1):

You are currently following demo application and I show there are lot of conflicts. But your aim here is to experiment with Angular and Firebase. I'm suggesting you to follow these steps.

Before that create a new Angular project.

eg.

```typescript
ng new my-app
```

Now install the angularfire2 and firbase:

```node
npm install angularfire2 firebase --save
```

Add Firebase config to environments variable:

```typescript
firebase: {
    apiKey: '<your-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-project-authdomain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-URL>',
    projectId: '<your-project-id>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>',
    messagingSenderId: '<your-messaging-sender-id>'
  }
```

Setup `@NgModule` for the `AngularFireModule` and `AngularFireAuthModule` :

```typescript
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In you `AppComponent`  import `AngularFireAuth` and `auth`:

```typescript
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase';
```

And implement following functions:

```typescript
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }
  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div *ngIf="afAuth.user | async as user; else showLogin">
  <h1>Hello {{ user.displayName }}!</h1>
  <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
</div>
<ng-template #showLogin>
  <p>Please login.</p>
  <button (click)="login()">Login with Google</button>
</ng-template>
```

These steps are same as their [DOC](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). Please refer bellow links:

- [Installation and Setup](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md)
- [Getting started with Firebase Authentication](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: made the suggested changes and I am still getting the same console error.

Comment: Looked at the projects github and the release history they introduced a breaking change where you need to use `auth` from firebase now not import */firbase. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases/tag/5.0.0-rc.10

Comment: @Buster it's better to follow the updated answer steps

Comment: Thanks I should have tried taking back to bare minimum thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this issue, I eventually fixed it by deleting everything out of my node modules folder, deleting the package lock file and the running `npm install`.